# Indexing in DBMS

Tags: database, indexing, sparse-matrix

So in primary index we have sorted data and we selecting search key as primary or candidate key.
But does secondary indexing used for unsorted data ?

Is clustering index a part of Primary index.
what does sparse and dense means

Comment: We can't tell from the tags or the question which database language or package you are using.  Don't expecct us to guess.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am using Relational Database